# C# Unity: unable to change the color of a Particle system in the script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How would I change the color of my effect variable in the start method. I tried it with`effect.startColor = Color.red` but it simply will not change the color. Could it not be working because my death effect is a prefab used by all instances of this script?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Obstacle : Living {

    public ParticleSystem deathEffect;
    public Material obstacleMaterial;

    ParticleSystem effect;

    public void Start(){
        effect = deathEffect;


    }

    public override void TakeHit (float damage, Vector3 hitPoint, Vector3 bulletDirection){

        AudioManager.instance.PlayFx ("Impact", transform.position);

        if (health <= damage) {
            AudioManager.instance.PlayFx ("EnemyDeath", transform.position);
            ParticleSystem newEffect = Instantiate (effect, hitPoint, Quaternion.FromToRotation (Vector3.forward, bulletDirection)) as ParticleSystem;

            Destroy (newEffect, newEffect.startLifetime);

        }
        base.TakeHit (damage, hitPoint, bulletDirection);
    }
```

Comment: You don't even try to change it in the code you posted... Did you try with ...startColor = new Color(....); (i.e. with "new" keyword)?

Comment: yes thats what I wrote in the description...nice one:-)

Comment: No, you did not write this. I asked about using the 'new' keyword, i.e.  "... = **new** Color(...);"